# IF formula to subtract from amount in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am setting up a Google Sheets spreadsheet with a few columns as follows:-

```
Pref|Room|Item|Price|Got
```

I have a formula to add up the total of all the cells based on the room and if they are a preferred item:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D50,A2:A50, "Y", B2:B50, "Living Room")
```

I am trying to create a formula so that I can take the total from the above formula and then subtract that item from the total to make a remaining amount based on the value of the `got` column

Comment: Welcome. On this site tags should not be included on the question title, questions should be specific, about using a web application and it should be named on the question body. What web application are you using?

Comment: Good to know that the question is about Google Sheets. Have you tried to build the formula you are looking for? Where did you get stuck?